# Issues installing gems due to ruby versions

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've installed rails and ruby using homebrew and following a break from coding, have recently attempted to upgrade my packages.

When running:

```
bundle install --without production
```

I receive the following error message:

```
Gem::InstallError: listen requires Ruby version ~> 2.2.
An error occurred while installing listen (3.1.1), and Bundler cannot     continue.
Make sure that `gem install listen -v '3.1.1'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Checking via brew update, I have `ruby 2.3` so am unclear why this will not install.

Additionally, when I try to check my rails version, I receive the following error.

```
Could not find gem 'rails_12factor (= 0.0.2) ruby' in the gems available on this machine.
```

I'd appreciate a recommendation of a good tutorial to enable me to go back through the update process or a quick fix?

Thank you

Comment: which version of ruby declared in Gemfile?

Comment: I've declared rails '4.2.2' but not ruby.  When I declare ruby without a version, it fails as above.  If I try to force a version it fails and cannot find the version.

Comment: show output `bundle exec ruby -v`

Comment: in my investigations i've installed ruby for 2.3.0 version successfully...

Comment: ruby 2.1.2p95 (2014-05-08 revision 45877) [x86_64-darwin14.0]

Comment: that is incorrect version )))

Comment: and running 'brew upgrade ruby' returns 'Error: ruby 2.3.0 already installed'

Comment: have you use rvm/rbenv?

Comment: yes, it is installed but don't pick up

Comment: provide path to bundle: `which bundle`

Comment: /Users/mhairi/.rbenv/shims/bundle

Comment: i'm now confused as i've not used rvm/rbenv before.

Comment: but youve used rbenv, so just install ruby 2.3.0 with rbenv

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-ruby-on-rails-with-rbenv-on-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: http://octopress.org/docs/setup/rbenv/

Comment: Ruby 2.3 is not ~> 2.2.  Ruby 2.3 is > 2.2.  If you must use the listen gem, try using a 2.2 version of ruby.

Comment: thank you all.  it's now working - i think what had happened is that in my updating everything, i'd broken the PATH to rbenv from my bash_profile.  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the bundler chokes on particular gems, like you saw. What I find works is simply to do what the error message tells you, install the gem standalone. And then run the bundler again. It make give you another error for different gem..

```
$gem install listen -v '3.1.1'

$bundle install --without production
```

And see if you get another

> Make sure that `gem xxxx l-v '9.9.9'` succeeds before bundling.

And then install that gem standalone. And so on.

In this way, you step through the bundler and individually install the gems.  And do so until you get a clean bundle. I have not seen this documented anywhere, but sometimes this is the only way I've found to get a bundle set up for the first time.

*Caveat: Let me know if the Ruby version error is still a problem. I can't account for that. It could be spurious or a different issue.*

Comment: that is not good approach, because list should be installed to the same env

Comment: It is the same environment. You'll never get through the bundler until you install the gems per the error message. It is telling you what you need to do. You just need to do it.

Comment: You're not the OP. Curious what your solution is...please post.

Comment: Thank you but I'm afraid that made no difference - it's still claiming the Ruby version error.

Comment: Do you get the version error  when you do this command? $gem install listen -v '3.1.1'

Comment: What do you see when you run $ruby -v

Comment: thank you for your help - I think the PATH to call rbenv from bash_profile was broken so it wasn't picking up the right version of ruby.  it's all sorted now.  thank you.

Comment: Glad to hear you resolved the problem. And thanks for following up. Nice.